# Ошибка в вычислениях NaN

Tags: javascript

```
function areaRectangle8(){
    this.calc2();
var m1 = document.forma1.t26.value||0;
    var p1 = document.forma1.t27.value||0;
    var p2 = document.forma1.t28.value||0;
    var p = (1+m1)*p1*p2/(p2+m1*p1);


    if ( (m1 == 0) || (p1 == 0) || (p2 == 0) ) {
        alert('Входные данные не могут быть равны 0');
        return;
    }

    if ( (m1 < 0) || (p1 < 0) || (p2 < 0) ) {
        alert('Входные данные не могут быть меньше 0');
        return;
    }
    var V=document.forma1.t30.value||0;
    var G=(p*V)/(1+m1);
    document.forma1.res8.value=G.toFixed(2);
}

function calc2() { //в подрасчёте есть промежуточное значение p
    console.log(1); //пользователь узнает чему равно p, только после ввода p1,p2 и m

    var m1 = +document.forma1.t26.value||0;
    var p1 = +document.forma1.t27.value||0;
    var p2 = +document.forma1.t28.value||0;
    var p = (1+m1)*p1*p2/(p2+m1*p1);

    document.forma1.t29[0].value = m1;
    document.forma1.t29[1].value = p1;
    document.forma1.t29[2].value = p2;
    document.forma1.t29[3].value = p.toFixed(2);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    document.forma1.t26.addEventListener("keyup", calc2);
    document.forma1.t27.addEventListener("keyup", calc2);
    document.forma1.t28.addEventListener("keyup", calc2);
});
        var m1=+document.forma1.t26.value||0;
        var p1=+document.forma1.t28.value||0;
        var p2=+document.forma1.t29.value||0;
        var V=document.forma1.t30.value||0;

        if ( (m1 == 0) || (p1 == 0) || (p2 == 0) )
        {
            alert('Входные данные не могут быть равны 0');
            return;
        }

        if ( (m1 < 0) || (p1 < 0) || (p2 < 0) )
        {
            alert('Входные данные не могут быть меньше 0');
            return;
        }
            var G = (p*V)/(1+m1);
        document.forma1.res8.value = G.toFixed(2);
    }

    function calc2() { //в подрасчёте есть промежуточное значение p
        console.log(1); //пользователь узнает чему равно p, только после ввода p1,p2 и m

        var m1 = +document.forma1.t26.value||0;
        var p1 = +document.forma1.t27.value||0;
        var p2 = +document.forma1.t28.value||0;
        var p = (1+m1)*p1*p2/(p2+m1*p1);

        document.forma1.t29[0].value = m1;
        document.forma1.t29[1].value = p1;
        document.forma1.t29[2].value = p2;
        document.forma1.t29[3].value = p.toFixed(2);
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        document.forma1.t26.addEventListener("keyup", calc2);
        document.forma1.t27.addEventListener("keyup", calc2);
        document.forma1.t28.addEventListener("keyup", calc2);
    });


<form name="forma1" style="background-color:#44944A;"> <!-- поменяю цвет формы -->
<div id="resizable">
<br>
        <table align="center">
        <p align="center">Количество сухого тампонажного цемента</p>
        <tr><td height="40px">
        <div class="price">Жидкостно-цементное отношение;</div><input name="t26" id="t29" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8"  onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td height="40px">
        <div class="price">Плотность цемента т/м<sup>3</sup>.</div><input name="t27" id="t29" type="text" align="right" size="4"  maxlength="8"  onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td height="40px">
        <div class="price">Плотность жидкости затворения, т/м<sup>3</sup>.</div><input name="t28" id="t29" type="text" align="right" size="4"  maxlength="8"  onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td height="40px">
        <div class="price">Плотность тампонажного раствора;</div><input name="t29" id="t29" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8"  onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td height="40px">
        <div class="price">Общий объем тампонажного раствора;</div><input name="t30" id="t30" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8"  onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
        <input type="button" name="button" value="Вычислить" onClick="areaRectangle8();">
        <input type="text" name="res8" size="10">
        </td></tr>
        </table>
</div>
<br>
</form>
```

Comment: Приложите полный код вместе с разметкой. Здесь как минмум нет функции calc1, перменные D2 и D3 не определены. Лучше всего оформите пример на jsfiddle.

Comment: исправил ошибки на которые мне указали

Comment: А где тег <form name="forma1"> ? Я поместил таблицу в форму и у меня всё посчиталось

Comment: У меня тоже таблица в форме

Comment: Свой скрипт (в вопросе) я немного изменил,но он всё ещё не работает

Comment: этот код я понимаю слабо, но первое что бросается в глаза, нету функции "return proverka(this)" , более того использовать пробел в названии функции не рекомендуется

Comment: на мой взгляд этот код в таком виде никогда не заработает, лично по мне его проще переписать с нуля

Answer (score 1):

Если вы приложили весь код, то проблема в том, что функция *areaRectangle8* нигде не вызывается.

Учитывая, что в ней вызывается *calc2* (кстати, зачем через this?), можно предположить, что в качестве обработчика события keyup нужно устанавливать именно *areaRectangle8*.

**UPD**: Теперь, когда вы приложили форму, видно, что дело вот в этом коде:

```
document.forma1.t29[0].value = m1;
document.forma1.t29[1].value = p1;
document.forma1.t29[2].value = p2;
document.forma1.t29[3].value = p;
```

В вашей форме есть только элемент с именем **t29**, а код пытается записать значения в четыре элемента с именем **t29[0]***...***t29[3]**. Поскольку таких полей на странице нет, функция завершается ошибкой и до конца не выполняется.

Comment: весь код с формой

Comment: Обновил ответ. Вы приложили всё-таки не весь код, есть ещё функция *proverka*, но я её проигнорировал, думаю, там ничего особенного.

Comment: Приложите работающий код в вопрос...

Answer (score 0):

Вот попробуйте

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    function areaRectangle8() {
        var m1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('t26').value || 0);
        var p1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('t28').value || 0);
        var p2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('t29').value || 0);
        var V = parseFloat(document.getElementById('t30').value || 0);
        if ( (m1 == 0) || (p1 == 0) || (p2 == 0) )
        {
            return alert('Входные данные не могут быть равны 0');
        }

        if ( (m1 < 0) || (p1 < 0) || (p2 < 0) )
        {
            return alert('Входные данные не могут быть меньше 0');
        }

        var p = (1+m1)*p1*p2/(p2+m1*p1);
                console.log(p);
        var G = (p*V)/(1+m1);
                console.log(G);
        document.getElementById('res8').value = G.toFixed(2);
    }
</script>
<table align="center">
    <p align="center">Количество сухого тампонажного цемента</p>
    <tr><td height="40px">
        <div class="price">Жидкостно-цементное отношение;</div><input id="t26" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td height="40px">
        <div class="price">Плотность цемента т/м<sup>3</sup>.</div><input id="t27" type="text" align="right" size="4"  maxlength="8">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td height="40px">
        <div class="price">Плотность жидкости затворения, т/м<sup>3</sup>.</div><input id="t28" type="text" align="right" size="4"  maxlength="8">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td height="40px">
        <div class="price">Плотность тампонажного раствора;</div><input id="t29" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td height="40px">
        <div class="price">Общий объем тампонажного раствора;</div><input id="t30" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>
        <input type="button" name="button" value="Вычислить" onClick="areaRectangle8()">
        <input type="text" id="res8" name="res8" size="10">
        </td></tr>
</table>
```

ваш код я непонимаю, непонимаю что за нотация *document.forma1.t29* особенно учитывая что форм на странице нету, далее много ошибок в парах *name/id* HTML тэгов, не понимаю зачем нужен *addEventListener*, и если код будет не только для себя надо сделать обработчик на поля чтобы давал писать только цифры и правил символ ***","*** на ***"."*** , а то будет ошибка вычисления, к стати для ошибок лучше сделать нередактируемое поле и кидать ошибки туда, использовать **alert** это архаизм.

Comment: так ничего не работает, а в моем скрипте хотя бы p считается

Comment: Наконец-то я исправил свой скрипт и теперь он правильно работает, но при вводе данных он выдаёт ошибку NaN, можно ли её как-нибудь обойти или исправить,чтобы она не вывдоилась? Эта ошибка у меня взникает когда я ввожу данные для подсчёта p, а ведь там происходит деление
Исправленный скрипт кидаю в вопрос

Comment: у меня мой код работает прекрасно и считает всё нормально,  а вот ваш код в хроме вообще ничего не выводит, поправил на NAN ошибку

Comment: у меня яндекс браузер, консоли в нём нет по умолчанию,а где скачать и как устанавливать её я незнаю